# How do I disable SQL Reporting Services and remove the Reports directory form IIS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis-7, reporting-services, report

I'm trying to get rid of the /reports directory which seems to be integrated with SQL reporting services 2008.  I'm unable to uninstall that one element of SQL server and I've had no luck when trying to reconfigure the ReportBuilderLaunchURL.  Does anyone out there know how I can get rid of this stupid feature?  I'd understand if it was just a virtual directory on the localhost instance but when it gets applied to all my site I get really frustrated and wonder who at Microsoft decided that this would be the default setting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For future reference:

Use the "reporting services configuration manager".

In the report manager URL tab insert a new virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you uninstall SSRS by going through the installation process of SQL Server itself and selecting to remove a certain component (SSRS in this case).

Alternatively (probably better) is to go to the Add/Remove programs menu and select SQL Server and hit the "change" button. From there you will be given the option of the components you want to repair/install/uninstall/etc.

**Edit**: Here is an article I found which attempts to describe how to [uninstall SSRS 2008](http://icu-mscrm.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-uninstall-sql-server-2008.html). It seems to agree with what I was saying about the Add/Remove programs idea.

Comment: I tried that but it wants to remove the entire instance.  I'm running hte developer edition which might have somehtign to do with it.  I don't get these problems on release just when I develop on my local machine.

Comment: All my experience comes from SQL Server 2005, so there may be differences. I know Reporting Services between 2005 and 2008 changed dramatically, but I would imagine that you should still be able to choose what components you want to uninstall instead of having to go completely from scratch and back again.

Answer (score 0):

We've just been having this issue and the work around we came up with was linking it to one specific host header, rather than having it point to all sites on all IP addresses. (You can do this by clicking on the advanced button in the URL tab that @Luis mentions.) This has, effectively, quarantined the thing to one website and as it's a host header that isn't on any public site in the first place, it's massively limited the number of people who can even find it.